# form control value gives with edit form empty value or empty string

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

```
                          #form control gives me empty string#
```

---

1-I'm Tring to get value of any form control with edit form (edit customer form) and it gives me empty string or empty value during print it in console becuase I will depend on values of form controls in most cases during (change) method to hide and show other input and make my businness logic how I can overcome this Proplem ? altough this value i got it rightly in other form (add customer form) **

---

```js
    import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
    import { CustomersDetailsService } from 'src/app/services/customers-details.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-customer-edit',
      templateUrl: './customer-edit.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./customer-edit.component.scss'],
      providers: [MessageService],
    })
    export class CustomerEditComponent implements OnInit {
      serviceProvID: any;
      serviceQotaID: any;
      UserID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}')?.ID;
      UserRole = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}')?.Role;
      page: any = 1;
      PageLimit: any = 25;
      CustomerType: any;
      totalCount: any;
      governorate: any = [];
      todayDate = new Date();
      offers: any = [];
      RequestTypes: any = [];
      quota: any = [];
      providerService: any = [];
      cutomerStatus: any = [];
      routerType: any = [];
      customerType: any = [];
      GovernateID: any;
      cities: any = [];
      deliverMethod: any = [];
      createdBy = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}')?.ID;
      tomorrow = new Date(this.todayDate.getTime());
      editCustomer!: FormGroup;
      RequestNumber!: FormControl;
      customerTypeID!: FormControl;
      name!: FormControl;
      nationalId!: FormControl;
      address!: FormControl;
      fixedLine!: FormControl;
      nearestFixedLine!: FormControl;
      mobile!: FormControl;
      governorateID!: FormControl;
      city!: FormControl;
      District!: FormControl;
      SpecialMark!: FormControl;
      central!: FormControl;
      serviceProviderID!: FormControl;
      offerID!: FormControl;
      serviceQuotaID!: FormControl;
      customerStatusID!: FormControl;
      RouterTypeID!: FormControl;
      RouterDeliveryMethodID!: FormControl;
      RequestTypeID!: FormControl;
      ContactDate!: FormControl;
      Comment!: FormControl;
      RejectedReason!: FormControl;
      CustomerID: any;
      pattern = '^01[0-2,5]{1}[0-9]{8}$';
    
      isShowRequestNumber: boolean = false;
      isShowFixedLine: boolean = false;
      isShowNearstFixedLine: boolean = false;
      isShowRouterAndRouterDeliveryMethod: boolean = false;
      isShowRejectedReason: boolean = false;
    
      private unsubscribe: Subscription[] = [];
    
      constructor(
        private apiservice: ApiService,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private customersDetailsService: CustomersDetailsService,
        private messageService: MessageService,
        private router: Router
      ) {
        this.initFormControl();
        this.createForm();
      }
      initFormControl() {
        this.RequestNumber = new FormControl('');
        this.customerTypeID = new FormControl('');
        this.name = new FormControl('');
        this.nationalId = new FormControl('');
        this.address = new FormControl('');
        this.fixedLine = new FormControl('');
        this.nearestFixedLine = new FormControl('');
        this.mobile = new FormControl('');
        this.governorateID = new FormControl('');
        this.city = new FormControl('');
        this.District = new FormControl('');
        this.SpecialMark = new FormControl('');
        this.central = new FormControl('');
        this.serviceProviderID = new FormControl('');
        this.offerID = new FormControl('');
        this.serviceQuotaID = new FormControl('');
        this.customerStatusID = new FormControl('');
        this.RouterTypeID = new FormControl('');
        this.RouterDeliveryMethodID = new FormControl('');
        this.ContactDate = new FormControl('');
        this.RequestTypeID = new FormControl('');
        this.Comment = new FormControl('');
        this.RejectedReason = new FormControl('');
      }
    
      createForm() {
        this.editCustomer = new FormGroup({
          customerTypeID: this.customerTypeID,
          RequestNumber: this.RequestNumber,
          name: this.name,
          nationalId: this.nationalId,
          address: this.address,
          fixedLine: this.fixedLine,
          nearestFixedLine: this.nearestFixedLine,
          mobile: this.mobile,
          governorateID: this.governorateID,
          city: this.city,
          District: this.District,
          SpecialMark: this.SpecialMark,
          central: this.central,
          serviceProviderID: this.serviceProviderID,
          offerID: this.offerID,
          serviceQuotaID: this.serviceQuotaID,
          customerStatusID: this.customerStatusID,
          RouterTypeID: this.RouterTypeID,
          RouterDeliveryMethodID: this.RouterDeliveryMethodID,
          ContactDate: this.ContactDate,
          RequestTypeID: this.RequestTypeID,
          Comment: this.Comment,
          RejectedReason: this.RejectedReason,
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.CustomerID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    
        this.getAddCustLookups();
        this.customersDetailsService
          .getCustomerDetails(+this.CustomerID)
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.customerType = res.Customer.CustomerTypeID;
    
            this.serviceProvID = res.Customer.ServiceProviderID;
            this.addInOfferQuota(this.serviceProvID);
            this.serviceQotaID = res.Customer.ServiceQuotaID;
            this.addInServiceOffers(this.serviceQotaID);
            this.editCustomer = new FormGroup({
              RequestNumber: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['RequestNumber'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              customerTypeID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['CustomerTypeID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              name: new FormControl(res.Customer['Name'], Validators.required),
              nationalId: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['NationalId'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              address: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['Address'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              fixedLine: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['FixedLine'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              nearestFixedLine: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['NearestFixedLine'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              mobile: new FormControl(res?.Customer['Mobile'], [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern(this.pattern),
              ]),
              governorateID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['GovernorateID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              city: new FormControl(res?.Customer['City'], Validators.required),
              District: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['District'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              SpecialMark: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['SpecialMark'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              central: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['Central'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              serviceProviderID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['ServiceProviderID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              offerID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['OfferID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              serviceQuotaID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['ServiceQuotaID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              customerStatusID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['CustomerStatusID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              RouterTypeID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['RouterTypeID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              RouterDeliveryMethodID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['RouterDeliveryMethodID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              ContactDate: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['ContactDate'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              RequestTypeID: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['RequestTypeID'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              Comment: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['Comment'],
                Validators.required
              ),
              RejectedReason: new FormControl(
                res?.Customer['RejectedReason'],
                Validators.required
              ),
            });
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          });
      }
    
      updateForm() {
        document.getElementById('button-2')?.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
        this.customersDetailsService
          .updateCurrentCustomer(
            this.editCustomer.value,
            this.UserID,
            this.CustomerID
          )
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            if (res.status === 'successfully') {
              this.editedCust();
              if (this.customerType == 22) {
                this.router.navigate(['/adsl-list']);
              } else if (this.customerType == 23) {
                this.router.navigate(['/fixed-list']);
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/fixed-adsl']);
              }
            } else {
              this.ErrorInEditedCust();
            }
            document.getElementById('button-2')?.removeAttribute('disabled');
          });
      }
    
      editedCust() {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'you modified Customer Successfly',
          detail: 'تم تعديل عميل بنجاح',
        });
      }
      ErrorInEditedCust() {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'error',
          summary: 'Customer not modifided Yet',
          detail: 'لم يتم تعديل عميل بعد',
        });
      }
    
      addInOfferQuota(serviceProvID: any) {
        this.apiservice
          .GetServiceQuota(this.serviceProvID)
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.quota = res.Lookups.ServiceQuota;
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          });
      }
    
      addInServiceOffers(ServiceQota: any) {
        this.apiservice.getOffer(this.serviceQotaID).subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.offers = res.Lookups.Offer;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
      }
      getAddCustLookups() {
        this.apiservice.getAddCustomerLookUps().subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.customerType = res.Lookups.CustomerType;
          this.governorate = res.Lookups.Governorate;
          this.providerService = res.Lookups.ServiceProvider;
          this.cutomerStatus = res.Lookups.CustomerStatus;
          this.routerType = res.Lookups.RouterType;
          this.deliverMethod = res.Lookups.RouterDeliveryMethod;
          this.RequestTypes = res.Lookups.RequestType;
    
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
      }
    
      providerChange(event: Event) {
        let value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.apiservice.GetServiceQuota(value).subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.quota = res.Lookups.ServiceQuota;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
      }
    
    
      **changetStatus() {
        console.log('=>', this.customerStatusID.value);
        if (this.customerStatusID.value == 17) {
          this.isShowRejectedReason = true;
        }
      }**
   
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe.forEach((sb) => sb.unsubscribe());
         }
      }
```

Comment: Did you declare FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule modules at app.module?

Comment: You're declared a large quantity of FormsControls, a function initForm() and a createForm() that **it's not used** (and you **should remove at all**), and when you subscribe to the service give value to your "editCustomer" formGroup. I imagine you're using in the .html, the formControls declared at first that has no relation with the real FormGroup

Comment: how i can init editcustomer form and get value for every control ?